# Index.html in root domain not getting server side rendering in angular IIS

Tags: node.js, angular, iis, server-side-rendering, iisnode

I am using angular 4 hosted on IIS.Also,I am using IISnode (https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) for server side rendering.so in my **web.config** I made rule to rewrite all my request to server.js which is node file so that server side rendering happens.Here is the rule.

Config:

```
<rule name="Angular">
                 <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" /> 
                             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>

                        <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
                </rule>
```

The server.ts file generates server.js file.Here is the code.

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';


// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), '/');

// Our index.html we'll use as our template
const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER,'index.html')).toString();

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    // DI so that we can get lazy-loading to work differently (since we need it to just instantly render it)
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER));

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER)));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'index.html'), { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

The problem is for all the routes, server side rendering works .But for root domain '/' it does not do server side rendering and plain index.html is served from server.I have screenshot for response header. 
so,for all other routes,response header  is.

[image]

You can see it is powered by ASP.NET and express both.But for root domain response header is:

[image]

It is powered by just ASP.NET.

I am not able to find reason why main root route is not served by server side rendering.